# How to display a list of users tagged with taxonomy term, but taxonomy term already used in another display

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

I have a taxonomy vocabulary . I already have a view set-up that displays each committee's page using the '/taxonomy/term/%' display. This works great.

Committee:
   - Committee #1
   - Committee #2

My issue is that I would like to have another display that shows committee members (set up as drupal users) that have been tagged with a committee using the term reference field.

- Committee #1

  - Committee #1's Users
- Committee #2

  - Committee #2's Users

How would I get this work. I can't use the path '/taxonomy/term/%' again.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I you just want a view you can use any path you desire, as long as you have the correct contextual filters. Clone the existing view and adapt the path and whatever else you need.